# Div inside a new div with appendchild

Tags: javascript

I have this function that create a new div with a class name.
Now I want to add a new div inside the created div. But nothing happened. When I look in the console with Chrome, nothing gets rendered inside the new div...

Any ideas?

```
function diceWrapper(){
    var wrappId=document.createElement("div");
    document.getElementById("page-content-wrapper").appendChild(wrappId);
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[3].setAttribute("class", "dice-window-wrapper");
}

function menubar(){
    var menuid=document.createElement("div");
    document.getElementById("dice-window-wrapper").appendChild(menuid);
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[4].setAttribute("class", "dice-menubar-wrapper");
}
```

And while I'm already asking, the new created `<div class="dice-window-wrapper"`.
Keeps pushing down some other elements that are suposed to be before this div class. Even when the attributes are `[0]` and `[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to find the newly created `<div>` and then modify it. It would be better to make all modifications first and only then add it to the document.

```
function createElementWithClass(elementName, className)
{
    var el = document.createElement(elementName);

    el.className = className;

    return el;
}

var outerDiv = createElementWithClass('div', 'dice-window-wrapper'),
innerDiv = createElementWithClass('div', 'dice-menubar-wrapper');

outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);

document
  .getElementById("page-content-wrapper")
  .appendChild(outerDiv);
```

Comment: Hey, just as you wrote i was trying to find a newly created <div> . this did the trick to find the new <div> Will read some more about inner and outerDiv since this would help me more with the project.
Thank you :)

Comment: The code you gave me works perfect, but I cant seem to use it to create a new div inside the newly created <div class"dice-menubar-wrapper">

Its like before, when im trying to reach an new ID.
any tips :)?

Comment: @Dymond just create an inner inner div and append to inner div, same thing really :)

Comment: haha. Well... thats what im trying with but cant get it right.

I created a innerinnerDiv=createElementWithClass("div", "close");
and want to input the div inside dice-menubar-wrapp.
document.getElementById("page-content-wrapper").appendChild(innerDiv);

But nothing seems to happen when i look in the console :(

Comment: @Dymond no, call appendChild() on the variable innerDiv before its added to the document.